# Tell me how to work with static files in CloudFlare

Tags: deployment, cloudflare

I'm new to CloudFlare and I'm having a problem. My static files are not read or cached. I can't figure out how to work with them.
When I go to my website I get errors like 404 (/static/dashboard/index.js) and so with all static files.
I cleared the cache and then I get these errors.

Please tell me what I need to do to make it work

I tried restarting nginx, and also cleared the cache from another domain that is running on a different virtual machine and no errors occurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 404 in Cloudflare side, it looks like your nginx didn't send this static files at all.

- I suggest to check and fix your nginx first, without Cloudflare.
- After that, you need to make sure that your DNS records setupped as a Proxied, not "DNS only".
- And after all above correctly configured, Cloudflare will start to cache your static files with [standart configuration](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/default-cache-behavior/). And you can modify that by utilizing [page rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427)